# Finding intersection between two object arrays based on field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In mongo collection I have documents of following structure.

```
{
    "_id" : "Suzuki",
    "qty" : 10,
    "plates" : [ 
        {
            "rego" : "1QX-WA-123",
            "date" : 1516374000000.0
        }, 
        {
            "rego" : "1QX-WA-456",
            "date" : 1513369800000.0
        }
    ],
    "accounts" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "23kpi9MD4KnTvnaW7",
            "createdAt" : 1513810712802.0,
            "date" : 1503446400000.0,
            "type" : "Suzuki",
            "rego" : "1QX-WA-123",
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "2Wqrd4yofvLmqLm5H",
            "createdAt" : 1513810712802.0,
            "date" : 1501632000000.0,
            "type" : "Suzuki",
            "rego" : "1QX-WA-111",
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to filter objects in `accounts` array so that it contains only those objects whose `rego` exists in `plates` array.

I tried following query, however, it throws an error: `all operands of $setIntersection must be arrays. One argument if of type object.`

```
db.getCollection('dummy').aggregate([{
    $project: {
        plates: 1, 
        accounts: 1,
        intersect: {
            $setIntersection: [
                { $arrayElemAt: [ "$plates", 0 ] },
                { $arrayElemAt: [ "$accounts", 4 ] }
            ]
        }
    }
}])
```

The expected output I am looking for is:

```
{
    "_id" : "Suzuki",
    "qty" : 10,
    "plates" : [ 
        {
            "rego" : "1QX-WA-123",
            "date" : 1516374000000.0
        }, 
        {
            "rego" : "1QX-WA-456",
            "date" : 1513369800000.0
        }
    ],
    "accounts" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "23kpi9MD4KnTvnaW7",
            "createdAt" : 1513810712802.0,
            "date" : 1503446400000.0,
            "type" : "Suzuki",
            "rego" : "1QX-WA-123",
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are a couple of ways, but what you really are after is simply to [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) instead.

Using [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) would likely be the first choice:

```
db.getCollection('dummy').aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "accounts": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$accounts",
        "cond": {
          "$in": [ "$$this.rego", "$plates.rego" ]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Or if you don't have MongoDB 3.4 at least, then using [`$anyElementTrue`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/):

```
db.getCollection('dummy').aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "qty": 1,
    "plates": 1,
    "accounts": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$accounts",
        "as": "acc",
        "cond": {
          "$anyElementTrue": {
            "$map": {
              "input": "$plates.rego",
              "as": "rego",
              "in": { "$eq": [ "$$rego", "$$acc.rego" ] }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Or even [`$setIsSubset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/):

```
db.getCollection('dummy').aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "qty": 1,
    "plates": 1,
    "accounts": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$accounts",
        "as": "acc",
        "cond": {
          "$setIsSubset": [ ["$$acc.rego"], "$plates.rego" ]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

It's really not a [`$setIntersection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) for this type of operation, since that would need a comparison on "just the field values" as a "set", and the output is really just "that" and not the "objects".

You could do something silly with matching array indexes to the produced "set" positions:

```
db.getCollection('dummy').aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "accounts": {
      "$map": { 
        "input": { "$setIntersection": ["$plates.rego", "$accounts.rego"] },
        "in": {
          "$arrayElemAt": [
            "$accounts",
            { "$indexOfArray": [ "$accounts.rego", "$$this" ] }      
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

But in reality you probably really just want the [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) result as being far more practical. And if you want that output as a "set" then you can simply wrap the [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) output with a [`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) or like operator to make the entries "unique".

In all variations these return:

```
{
    "_id" : "Suzuki",
    "qty" : 10.0,
    "plates" : [ 
        {
            "rego" : "1QX-WA-123",
            "date" : 1516374000000.0
        }, 
        {
            "rego" : "1QX-WA-456",
            "date" : 1513369800000.0
        }
    ],
    "accounts" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "23kpi9MD4KnTvnaW7",
            "createdAt" : 1513810712802.0,
            "date" : 1503446400000.0,
            "type" : "Suzuki",
            "rego" : "1QX-WA-123"
        }
    ]
}
```

Showing the items in the `"accounts"` array *"filtered"* as matching the respective `"rego"` amounts from the `"plates"` array.